# Dynamic Context Binding in XML

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have odata coming from backend. I have two select controls on my SAPUI5 page. The first select displays a list of items received from the backend. The second select changes depending on what is selected from the first select control.

Right now I am constructing in the controller a new path for "planets" select. Is it possible to change the "planets" items path depending on the "stars" selected item just in the XML? Without using Javascript?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<Select id="stars"
    items="{
        path: '/Stars'
    }">
    <core:Item key="{StarID}" text="{StarName}" />
</Select>


<Select id="planets"
    items="{
        path: '("/Stars('" + StarID + "')/toPlanets"'
    }">
    <core:Item text="{PlanetName}" />
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not believe that there is any existing functionality to do something like this naively in UI5. The only thing that is similar is binding replacement during XML preprocessing, but you cannot use that for your situation.

I have met this situation a lot of times in the past and have created a helper control for dealing with this (might not be the perfect solution, but it works). It only makes sense to use a similar approach if you have this kind of construct in multiple places (so you avoid having the same boilerplate code in your JS controllers).

You can find [here](https://github.com/serban-petrescu/sbwo/blob/master/web/util/IndirectBindingWrapper.js) an example implementation of such a control and [here](https://github.com/serban-petrescu/sbwo/blob/master/web/fragment/edit/LocationFullForm.fragment.xml#L20) an example usage. Basically this allows you to have a reusable mechanism for doing such an "indirect binding" without resorting to event listeners.